# ubuntu likewise authentication for windows shares

Tags: windows, ubuntu, authentication, shares, likewise-open

I currently use likewise to use my active directory credentials to log on to ubutu (12.04). When I want to mount one of our windows shares, I am prompted for a password again. Is there a way to reuse or pass through my current credentials? I've seen some posts on this site regarding single sign on, but I'm not sure if/how likewise can play into this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on mounting the shares permanently through /etc/fstab? Or only when you need them? Also are you running Desktop GUI or CLI only for normal use?

Comment: They are in fstab but set to not automount.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did not. I just manually type in my password when prompted.

Comment: You can open file manager and select connect to server and type smb://servername to view the shares and then select the share and it will mount in file manager. You can then right click it and add to favorites. You can also view these mappings under /home/username/.gvfs to use for linux apps ie. music, photos and etc. If you are being prompted for a username/password this way then you are not authenticating to AD correctly. If you do this using /etc/fstab you can create a smbcredentials file under /root and tell fstab to use this file instead. Chmod 600 the smbcredentials file